# ZBXNEXT-245 2.2 issue

Tags: zabbix

I am trying to do this patch to the 2.2 version of zabbix, but i dont know to apply the patch to the frontends version 2.2 because there are differents .php elements that what are indicated for modify in the patch.

The url of the patch: https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-245

I really need this improvement to my front-ends, can anyone say me if is possible to apply this patch in zabbix 2.2, and how to proceed?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some dev work, because you want to apply patch for Zabbix 1.8 to Zabbix 2.2 -> difference is two major releases.